# LINQ Get Data from 2 tables in 1 join with group by

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables.

```
Department         |              Questions
ID     Name        |         DepartmentID   QTitle   QDescription
1       a          |             1           aaa          bbb
2       b          |             1           ddd          ccc      
3       c          |             2           eee          fff
                   |             2           ggg          hhh
```

|
I want grouping data with ViewModel and display in View. I can take grouped data with QTitle but QDescription not.

**Linq Query**

```
var questions= (from s in dbContext.Questions
                         join b in dbContext.Department
                         on s.DepartmentID equals b.ID
                         group s.QTitle by b.DepartmentID into g
                         select new QuestionGroupedViewModel
                         {
                             DepartmentName= g.Key,
                             QTitle= g.ToList()
                         }).ToList();
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class QuestionGroupedViewModel
    {
     public string DepartmentName{ get; set; }
     public List<string> QDescription{ get; set; }
     public List<string> QTitle{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var questions= (from s in dbContext.Questions
                         join b in dbContext.Department
                         on s.DepartmentID equals b.ID
                         group s by b.DepartmentName into g
                         select new QuestionGroupedViewModel
                         {
                             DepartmentName= g.Key,
                             QTitle= g.Select(x => x.QTitle).ToList(),
                             QDescription = g.Select(x => x.QDescription).ToList()
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting error Select clause. Cannot implicitly convert type string to system.Collections.Generic.List<string>. I added .ToList() after select. Thanx for helping.

Comment: @Developer007 - you will aslo face error ` DepartmentName= g.Key,` as group by done on ID element

Comment: Yes I tried, I change b.DepartmentName instead of b.DeparmentID